# Do I need a delegate to do this?

Tags: c#, delegates

I have an application where I have a number of DataGridViews that display information from a number of instances of a class.  The class has various properties, and I have a DataGridView for each of them.

In simple terms, I want the user to be able to update the values in the DataGridView, and then have a routine that takes that data and updates the class.

I can do this fairly easily, but I think there has got to be a more concise way of doing it, that I'm simply not clever enough to find myself!

How I currently do it is that I have a function that starts with the DataGridView associated with one of the properties, processes the data to specifically update that property.  Then I do the same with the next DataGridView and so on and so on.  The code for each DataGridView is almost identical, except for the name of the property that gets updated, and a type conversion to make sure that the DataGridViewCell contents are converted to the correct type for the property (Double and Int).

Now:  I have spent lots of time trying to research a cleaner way of doing this: Delegates, Wrapper classes with Abstract methods, Generics.  Problem is that I don't know exactly what to search for, but I figured that the best option is some sort of delegate with a Lambda to point to the property to update, and a type check on that property.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this, and so I can't really even begin to write code for it!

Here is the basic premise of what I have:

```
//Update Priorities
if (_PrioritiesGrid != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _PrioritiesGrid.Rows.Count - 1; i++)        //Ignore last row - it is blank for user added rows.
    {
        DataGridViewRow priorityRow = _PrioritiesGrid.Rows[i];
        DateTime productionDay = Convert.ToDateTime(priorityRow.Cells[0].Value);
        if (!storedDates.Contains(productionDay)) storedDates.Add(productionDay);
        for (int j = 1; j < priorityRow.Cells.Count; j++)
        {
            Well well = (Well)_PrioritiesGrid.Columns[j].Tag;
            if (_WellList.ContainsValue(well))
            {
                well.SetPriority(productionDay, Convert.ToInt32(priorityRow.Cells[j].Value));
            }
        }
    }
}

//Update Potentials
if (_PotentialsGrid != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _PotentialsGrid.Rows.Count - 1; i++)        //Ignore last row - it is blank for user added rows.
    {
        DataGridViewRow potentialsRow = _PotentialsGrid.Rows[i];
        DateTime productionDay = Convert.ToDateTime(potentialsRow.Cells[0].Value);
        if (!storedDates.Contains(productionDay)) storedDates.Add(productionDay);
        for (int j = 1; j < potentialsRow.Cells.Count; j++)
        {
            Well well = (Well)_PotentialsGrid.Columns[j].Tag;
            if (_WellList.ContainsValue(well))
            {
                well.SetPotential(productionDay, Convert.ToDouble(potentialsRow.Cells[j].Value));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Well.SetPotential() populates the instance of the Well Class with Data from the _PotentialsGrid; Well.SetPriority() populates the instance of the Well Class with Data from the _PrioritiesGrid.

I am envisaging some kind of delegate function that means I can go:

```
ProcessGrid(_PotentialsGrid, x=>x.SetPotentials()) and
ProcessGrid(_PrioritiesGrid, x=>x.SetPriorities())
```

The fact that SetPotentials and SetPriorities both take parameters (that I only get when I actually start reading the grid data) is an added complication!

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think going with delegates is a good idea. 
Please create a solution (or framework) for this based on **inversion of control**.

At a high level your function (or framework function) should take two **inputs** -

1. DataGridView (or better its abstraction) - So you should be able to specify which cells update you would like to track.
2. Delegate -  This will be an Action that needs to be invoked when the specified cell's value changes.
   Which cells to read and what to do with the read values will be part of the delegate.

Now everytime the cell's value changes, it will be the responsibility of the framework to invoke the delegate that you have passed (thus inversion of control). 
The delegate knows which cells to read & what to do with the read values.

Please write me a comment if any thing is unclear or if you would like to have some sort of working code.

---

### UPDATE 1 . Understanding that a sample usage for delegates is required. Providing a sample code

I took the code in a single function as you desired `ProcessGrid`

```
public void ProcessGrid(DataGridView gridView, Action<Well, DateTime, DataGridViewCell> operaiton)
        {
            if (gridView != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < gridView.Rows.Count - 1; i++)        //Ignore last row - it is blank for user added rows.
                {
                    DataGridViewRow priorityRow = gridView.Rows[i];
                    DateTime productionDay = Convert.ToDateTime(priorityRow.Cells[0].Value);
                     if (!storedDates.Contains(productionDay)) storedDates.Add(productionDay);
                    for (int j = 1; j < priorityRow.Cells.Count; j++)
                    {
                        Well well = (Well)gridView.Columns[j].Tag;
                          if (_WellList.ContainsValue(well))
                        {
                           // This is where the delegate will fire.
                            operaiton(well, productionDay, priorityRow.Cells[j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And this is how you can call this ProcessGrid funciton.

```
ProcessGrid(_PrioritiesGrid, (well, productionDay, cell) => { well.SetPriority(productionDay, Convert.ToInt32(cell.Value));});

ProcessGrid(_PotentialsGrid, (well, productionDay, cell) => { well.SetPotential(productionDay, Convert.ToDouble(cell.Value));});
```

I have not executed it, but I'm optimistic it'll work fine. If you have any issues or any part is unclear, please write me a comment.

Comment: Thanks.  I won't immediately try to link the delegate to the cell_changed (or whichever is the most appropriate event).  It gets a bit complicated (I have code for copying and pasting data, loading from a database etc, and so to update the classes whenever something changes also requires me to have lots of checks on how the change was made etc).  Right now, I'd like to focus just on a delegate to do the basic update.  Unfortunately, I don't really know where to start, so any examples would be appreciated.

Comment: @ainwood, I have implemented a sample usage based around delegates, as you requested. Please check it. I'm hopeful it'll serve your purpose.

Comment: Exactly what I was after, and works perfectly.  The best part is that I can see what you've done, and has really helped to understand.  Thanks!

Comment: @ainwood, Glad to know to know that :)